# Linq : Join tables take from table whose value is not null

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have four tables.

`ProductFormula`:

```
   Sku             Param1  Param2
   -------------------------------
   100203          1.2      1.1
   100204          1.3      1.0
   .....
   ....
```

`CategoryFormula`:

```
 CategoryId        Param1  Param2
 ---------------------------------
   382               1.5      1.2
   383               1.6      1.4
   .....
   ....
```

`Product`:

```
   Id    CategoryId 
  ------------------
   1     383
   2     384
```

`ProductVariant`:

```
   Id  ProductId   Sku
   --------------------------
   1     1         100203
   ....
```

I want to take record such that if product formula exists for product that should be taken otherwise of category using linq query.

Any help?

Comment: not very clear what you're asking

Answer (score 1):

I *think* I get the idea at what you're trying to achieve. Basically, you want to return a ProductFormula for a Product. If there is no ProductFormula for the specified product, fallback to returning a CategoryFormula.

This assumes a Product always has a ProductCategory and each category on its turn always has a CategoryFormula.

Note: In the sample below I've deliberately not chained everything into one big Linq query. That would be really cool to look at, but be ridiculous in terms of readability. I favor the last, and appended some comments to hopefully make everything more easier to understand:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns either a ProductFormula, if it exists for the specified Product, otherwise a general CategoryFormula.
    /// </summary>
    static dynamic RetrieveFormula(int productId)
    {
        // First, we need to combine the entities 'Product' with 'ProductVariant'. 
        // This because we need the 'SKU' to check if a ProductFormula exists:
        var combinedProducts = AllProducts.Join(

            // join 'Products' and 'ProductVariants'
            AllProductVariants, 
            product => product.Id,
            productvariant => productvariant.ProductId,
            (product, productvariant) => new {
                Product = product,
                Variant = productvariant
            })

            // create a 'merged', anonymous object which holds all the info we need
            .Select(p => new
            {
                ProductId = p.Product.Id,
                CategoryId = p.Product.CategoryId,
                SKU = p.Variant.SKU
            });    

        // With this in place, we can now fetch the requested record by 'productId'
        var product = combinedProducts.Single(p => p.ProductId == productId);

        // Finally, check if there's a ProductFormula
        if (AllProductFormulas.Any(p => p.SKU == product.SKU))
            // yes, there's a ProductFormula so return it
            return AllProductFormulas.Single(pv => pv.SKU == product.SKU);
        else
            // no, sorry - simply return the CategoryFormula instead
            return AllCategoryFormulas.Single(c => c.Id == product.ProductId);
    }
```

You explicitely asked for returning A, otherwise, B. Therefor, the function returns a dynamic result. You could just as well combine the result and return a dynamic set of properties instead. For best practices, you might want to introduce a super class to inherit from, or an interface.

Last tip: most modern ORM's, like [EntityFramework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/entityframework) and [ServerStack OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite) to name just a few, have built in relationships which will make your coding experience easier for these kind of related queries.

Hope this nailed it for you...